# Как сделать полосы прокрутки в java swing для JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Всем привет. Появилась проблема, не могу добавить полосы прокрутки в Java для JTextArea. Делал по разному и всё равно не получилось внизу код без добавления полосы прокрутки, кто сможет помочь, буду благодарен.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame win = new JFrame();
        win.setSize(640, 480);
        win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        win.setTitle("SimpleTextMaster 1.0");
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu File = new JMenu("Файл");
        JMenuItem newfile = new JMenuItem("Создать"); 
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Открыть"); 
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Сохранить"); 
        JMenu Edit = new JMenu("Редактировать");
        JMenuItem undo = new JMenuItem("Отменить"); 
        JMenuItem cut = new JMenuItem("Вырезать"); 
        JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Копировать");
        JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Вставить");
        JMenu Settings = new JMenu("Настройки");
        JMenuItem textcolor = new JMenuItem("Цвет текста"); 
        JMenuItem textsize = new JMenuItem("Размер текста"); 
        JMenuItem transfer = new JMenuItem("Перенос строки");
        JMenu Help = new JMenu("Помощь");
        JMenuItem help2 = new JMenuItem("Справка"); 
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("О программе"); 
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        ta.setText("Добро пожаловать в SimpleTextMaster 1!");
        
        File.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        Edit.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        newfile.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        open.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        save.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        undo.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        cut.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        copy.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        paste.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        Settings.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        textcolor.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        textsize.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        transfer.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        Help.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        help2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        about.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        
        
        
        win.add(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(File);
        File.add(newfile);
        File.add(open);
        File.add(save);
        menuBar.add(Edit);
        Edit.add(undo);
        Edit.add(cut);
        Edit.add(copy);
        Edit.add(paste);
        menuBar.add(Settings);
        Settings.add(textsize);
        Settings.add(textcolor);
        Settings.add(transfer);
        menuBar.add(Help);
        Help.add(help2);
        Help.add(about);
        win.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        win.add(ta);
        
        win.setVisible(true);
        menuBar.setVisible(true);
        File.setVisible(true);
        newfile.setVisible(true);
        open.setVisible(true);
        save.setVisible(true);
        ta.setVisible(true);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно задать JScrollPane и положить в неё JTextArea

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
win.add(sp);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!